# c++ how to detect compiler options as string

Tags: c++

Is there any way to retrieve the options which were used to compile a program? Example: `-Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security` etc...

I've seen programs that had this in about form, but I can't find if there is some macro that contains the options which were passed to compiler as a string.

Is there some simple, preferably cross-platform way to detect this so that I could do something like

```
char *options = GCC_COMPILER_FLAGS;
```

Comment: The language standard provides no access to this information. This is typically done by passing the compiler options in the makefile. `cc $(COPTS) -DGCC_COMPILER_FLAGS="$(COPTS)" file.cpp`

Comment: @RaymondChen Why is this not an answer? Want to upvote!

Comment: @leemes Because I'm too lazy to fill in the missing details that would make it a proper answer. Feel free to fill them in and post your own answer.

Comment: I think you posted pretty enough for me to understand how to do that, so I guess it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Check the CPPFLAGS environment variable, that usually has the flags which are used to compile a program.

Specifically if you looking to identify the compiler flags within a program it would not be possible.